# Equivariant map between cones is flat?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Assume I have a locally complete intersection scheme $X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{C}$ and and affine space $A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ ($n>0$), both endowed with a $\mathbb{C}^*$-action (for the latter it is the obvious one). Assume I have a $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariant morphism $f:X\rightarrow  A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=\mathrm{dim}\,X-n$. is it true that $f$ has equidimensional fibers? Because the domain is Cohen--Macaulay and the target is regular, this would imply that $f$ is flat.

I think that it should be false as stated.

P.S.: apparently, it is claimed [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/Tomas.pdf) in the proof of Lemma 7.1 that the answer is positive. There $X$ is the set of complex points of the cotangent bundle of the stack of principal $G$-bundles over a smooth projective curve of genus $g>1$, $G$ being a connected semisimple complex group, and the morphism is Hitchin map. My objection above should not apply because I think there should be some dense subset of $A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ where one can explicitly compute the dimension of the fiber.

EDIT: I think assuming that $X$ and $f$ are of finite type, we get that the dimension of any fiber has to be at least $dim\, X-n$. From upper semi-continuity of the dimension of the fiber, we get that the set $\{x\in X|\mathrm{dim}_x X_{f(x)}\leq m\}$ is open for any $m$. For $m=\mathrm{dim}\,X-n$ this set (coinciding with set $\{x\in X|\mathrm{dim}_x X_{f(x)}=m\}$) is also $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariant and contains $f^{-1}(0)$. Any open $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariant subset of $X$ containing $f^{-1}(0)$ has to coincide with $X$.